# Recurrence Relation of GetMax() Method

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, recursion, recurrence

what will be the Recurrence Relation of this method , I don't get it why it is solved as T(n) = T(n-1)+1 ? but the position the one changing (increasing) each recursive call?

```
  private static int getMaxRecursive(int[] arr,int pos) {
             if(pos == (arr.length-1)) {
                    return arr[pos];
             } else {           
                    return Math.max(arr[pos], getMaxRecursive(arr, pos+1));
             }
       }
```

Answer (score 2):

- T(n) is the time of `getMaxRecursive(arr,0)`.
- T(n-1) is the time of `getMaxRecursive(arr,1)`.
- ...
- T(1) is the time of `getMaxRecursive(arr,arr.length-1)`.

Where `n` is the length of the array.

In other words, `T(i)` is the running time of the method for an array of length `i`, which is the sub-array of `arr` starting at index `arr.length-i` and ending at index `arr.length-1`.

Therefore

```
T(n) = T(n-1) + the time of the Math.max() operation (which is constant) = T(n-1) + 1
```